# invalid literal for int() with base 10 - django - updated

Tags: django, models, radix, migrate

I am a django beginner, and
I am trying to make a child-parent like combo box, (bars depends on city depends on country) and I get this error.

**UPDATE: 
Changed the model and the default value for the foreign key,  but still the same error. Any help? thanks!**

this is models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID = 1 # id of Israel
class BarName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country

class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city

class Bar(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    city = ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field='country' , chained_model_field='country', auto_choose=True)
    name = ChainedForeignKey(BarName, chained_field='city', chained_model_field='city', auto_choose=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.city, self.country)
    class Admin:
        pass
```

from running 'python manage.py migrate':

```
➜  baromatix  python manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, bars, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  .......

    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 915, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DEFAULT VALUE'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this issue when deleting the **old migrations files** that django created.

Comment: Can you elaborate, for those of us who have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use id of `Country` for `foreignkey` default value:

```
DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID = id # id of Israel
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating Alon's Weissfeld answer:

I ran into the same problem and it was indeed fixed after I **deleted all the migration cache files** located here:

```
~\yourAppFolder\migrations\
```

**Do not delete __init__.py**