# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b ' '

Tags: django-models

I get that error when I am trying to add new columns to my `LeaveRequest` model and migrate changes to my `DB(postgresql)`. Below is the code.

```
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
leave_type = models.ForeignKey(LeaveType, null=False)
reason = models.TextField(max_length=200)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
start_date = models.DateField()
return_date = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.leave_type.name)
```

Comment: Does it show a line number error?

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134290/invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-django-updated) and give me feedback.